# Payment URL/metamask deeplink does not work for transferring USDT in Arbitrum network

Tags: metamask, payments, arbitrum

I generated the following deeplink with https://metamask.github.io/metamask-deeplinks/#

> https://metamask.app.link/send/pay-0xfd086bc7cd5c481dcc9c85ebe478a1c0b69fcbb9@42161/transfer?address=0xrecipient&uint256=1e5

- `0xfd086bc7cd5c481dcc9c85ebe478a1c0b69fcbb9` is the USDT contract address, see [contract on Arbiscan](https://arbiscan.io/token/0xfd086bc7cd5c481dcc9c85ebe478a1c0b69fcbb9)
- `42161`: arbitrum chain id: [Arbitrum network info](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4415758358299-Network-profile-Arbitrum)
- `uint256=1e5`: the amount to be sent, in this case `0.1`

And I receive: `Internal JSON-RPC error`

I tried all other combinations:

- transfer ETH on ethereum network: ok
- transfer ERC20 on ethereum network: ok
- transfer ETH on arbitrum network: ok

Only the combination above seems not to work

ref
[ERC-681: URL Format for Transaction Requests](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-681)

Comment: can you share the error's screenshot?

Comment: it just says `internal JSON-RPC error` that's it

Comment: What RPC are you hitting ?

Comment: RPC is a URL . Can you provide the code snippet or the screenshot of error ?

Comment: so I don't do the call myself. I use metamask and then metamask displays an alert with `internal JSON-RPC error`